# Can Visual Studio put timestamps in the build log?

Tags: visual-studio, build

In the build log I'd like to the start and end time of each project's compilation. Is there any way to get VS to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For VC++ builds you can enable build timing.  Go to Tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->VC++ Project settings and choose the option for 'Build Timing'

Comment: Note this doesn't actually put _timestamps_ in the build log.  However it reports the milliseconds used in each step.

Answer (score 39):

Other option is to increase level of MSBuild verbosity.

```
Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run ->
```

Set `MSBuild project build output verbosity` to `Normal`. That will give you output like this:

```
------ Build started: MyProject, Configuration: Debug x86 ------
Build started 24/03/2014 08:46:18.
...
Build succeeded.

Time Elapsed 00:00:05.18
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually does what the OP requested.

Comment: This should be the default really. Often I find it important to see when a solution/project was last built to make sure I'm running the current version. Could check the build artifacts I suppose :D

Answer (score 10):

A new way I found is to call the `Time` command in the post event *Pre* and *Post-build event command line:*

```
TIME /T
```

Comment: If you also want to display the date it can be done by using "DATE /T".

Comment: The Post-build suggestion helped as the Build end date/time stamp isn't emitted, and why do unnecessary mental gymnastics of adding Time Elapsed to the Build started?

Answer (score 0):

Not without modifying the actual project file (using a text editor) to add calls in to the MSBuild script targets.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution with script file...
Also includes Elapsed Time for the build for a project.

Create VBS file somewhere in your projects shared space "GetTime.vbs"
VBS Code ...

```
dim out : Set out = WScript.StdOut
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
dim regDir: regDir="HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\VB and VBA Program Settings\GetTime.vbs\"
dim msg: msg=""
dim s: s=""
dim e: e=""
dim st:st=""
' param s is start flag keyed to the application being built.
if wscript.arguments.named.exists("s") then
    s = wscript.arguments.named("s")
    objShell.RegWrite regdir & s,now
end if
if wscript.arguments.named.exists("e") then
    e = wscript.arguments.named("e")
    st = cdate(objShell.RegRead(regDir & e))
end if 

if e<>"" and isdate(st) then
    out.writeline e & " ENDED " & now & " ELAPSED " & datediff("s",cdate(st),now) & " seconds"
elseif e<>"" then
    out.writeline e & " ENDED " & now
elseif s<>"" then
    out.writeline s & " STARTED " & now
else
    out.writeline now
end if
```

Alter you Build Events to include this script with some parameters as such...
(You will need to alter the direcotry path relative to your output directory to find the file from multiple projects)

Prebuild Event Command Line ...

```
cscript "../../../../Scorecards/gettime.vbs" //B /s:"$(ProjectName)"
```

Post Build Event Command Line

```
cscript "../../../../Scorecards/gettime.vbs" //B /e:"$(ProjectName)"
```

Example output from multiple projects ...

```
2>  OPResources STARTED 7/9/2020 12:59:04 PM
2>  ...
2>  OPResources ENDED 7/9/2020 12:59:05 PM ELAPSED 1 seconds
1>  OPLib_WF STARTED 7/9/2020 12:59:04 PM
1>  ...
1>  OPLib_WF ENDED 7/9/2020 12:59:05 PM ELAPSED 1 seconds
4>------ Rebuild All started: Project: OPLib, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
4>  OPLib STARTED 7/9/2020 12:59:06 PM
4> ...
4>  OPLib ENDED 7/9/2020 12:59:10 PM ELAPSED 4 seconds
5>------ Rebuild All started: Project: PerfUpdater, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
6>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Scorecards2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
7>------ Rebuild All started: Project: SingleSignOn, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
7>  SingleSignOn STARTED 7/9/2020 12:59:10 PM
7>  ...
7>  SingleSignOn ENDED 7/9/2020 12:59:12 PM ELAPSED 2 seconds
```